# How can we trigger Jenkins build in iterative method

Tags: bash, jenkins, sh, jenkins-pipeline

I have two jobs in Jenkins upstream and downstream.

When I trigger upstream job, below files has to be renamed as package.xml and deploy to downstream in iterative way. How can I make this done with shell script. 
Any Idea?

```
pkg1.xml    
pkg2.xml    
pkg3.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure what you're trying to do with the second part (maybe file another more detailed question), but here's how to rename files:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  stages {
    stage('build') {
      steps {

        # you don't need to create these files.
        # this was just for my testing.
        sh 'touch pkg1.xml pkg2.xml pkg3.xml'

        sh "rename 's/pkg/package/' *"
      }
    }
  }
}
```